# Is `hash` on a number consistent within a single ruby process?

Tags: ruby, hash, hashcode

When you run `hash` on a number, will it always return the same value within the same ruby process?

It seems that `2.hash` always returns the same value within a single process of irb, but if you close and reopen irb, you get a different value. Will it always stay consistent for every number within a process?

I believe that ruby uses the memory location for at least certain objects to calculate the hash, is this the same for numbers? And if so, are two instances of a number always going to have the same memory location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed to be the same within one Ruby process. `Hash` relies on this fact to guarantee unique keys. Otherwise long-lived processes could end up with duplicate hash keys when an object gets a new `hash` value.

Regarding implementation and memory locations, the implementation of `hash` is **not** guaranteed by Ruby. The only requirement is:

> This function must have the property that `a.eql?(b)` implies `a.hash ==
>   b.hash`.

In YARV, for example, many objects do not exist in memory at all (e.g. Fixnums) and are simply identified by a special object ID. `x.object_id == x * 2 + 1` for any fixnum.

Comment: Fyi, I know that MRI and Opal also possess the property that `x.object_id == x * 2 + 1` for all Fixnums. Simple test: `(-1_000_000..1_000_000).all? {|x| x.object_id == x * 2 + 1}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `BasicObject#__id__` which will remain consistent for Fixnum(but can get weird with larger numbers) eg.

```
 2.__id__
 #=> 5
 a = 2
 a.__id__
 #=> 5
 b = 2 
 a.__id__ == b.__id__
 #=> true
```

Does not matter what the process is `2.__id__` will always return `5` please note this is not true for most objects e.g.

```
{}.__id__
#=> 23077320
{}.__id__
#=> 22453800
{}.__id__
#=> 21672516
```

[Docs on `BasicObject#__id__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-__id__)

> The same number will be returned on all calls to object_id for a given object, and no two active objects will share an id.
>   Note: that some objects of builtin classes are reused for optimization. This is the case for immediate values and frozen string literals.

This is where @max is correct with `__id__ == x * 2 + 1` Thus `2 * 2 + 1 #=> 5` but I am not sure if this changes across interpreters.

Answer (score -1):

**hash function:**

> Generates a Fixnum hash value for this object. This function must have
>   the property that a.eql?(b) implies a.hash == b.hash.
>
> The hash value is used along with eql? by the Hash class to determine
>   if two objects reference the same hash key. Any hash value that
>   exceeds the capacity of a Fixnum will be truncated before being used.
>
> The hash value for an object may not be identical across invocations
>   or implementations of Ruby. If you need a stable identifier across
>   Ruby invocations and implementations you will need to generate one
>   with a custom method.

Source: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-hash

*It wasnt too hard to search

Comment: Thanks! Good edits, and I didn't think to look under Object for the method definition for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure about that "not be same always even within the same process" part?

Comment: @muistooshort: Now I am not. hah.. I just interpreted the last para in the quote above as that. `Not be identical across invocations`. Is this wrong? 

Because I read for `Hash` that it is same across process.

Comment: One invocation of `/usr/bin/ruby` (or where ever it is) is a process. It is saying that if you `x = o.hash` in your script, the `x` won't necessarily be the same the next time you run that script. But `o.hash` has to be the same within one process or how would things like `some_hash[k]` work reliably?

Comment: You found the correct quote, but your answer is definitely wrong.